# C# Camera Follow Player on X-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I have a question like this. I want the camera to follow a player only on the x-axis. The simplest method is to make the MainCamera child for the target. This is a fairly easy method and makes the movement not with certain eruptions, or trembling, moving quite smoothly. The problem is that I would now like to make the MainCamera follow only on the x-axis. and I do not know how to do this condition.
Below you will see the code written by me, but this code does not work when the MainCamera is a child for the target.

```
 /// <summary>
/// Follows to given target on specified axis
/// </summary>
public class FollowerCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public bool followOnY = false;
    public bool followOnX = false;
    public bool constrainedOnX = false;
    public bool constrainedOnY = false;
    public float minY = 0f;
    public float maxY = 0f;
    public float minX = 0f;
    public float maxX = 0f;
    [ReadOnly]
    public Vector3 offset;

    private Vector3 originalPosition;
    private void Start()
    {
        originalPosition = transform.position;
        offset = transform.position - target.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if ((!followOnX && !followOnY) || target==null)
            return;
        transform.position = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 normalizedPosition = transform.position;
        if (followOnX)
        {
            if (constrainedOnX)
            {
                normalizedPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(normalizedPosition.x, minX, maxX);
            }
        }
        else
            normalizedPosition.x = originalPosition.x;
        if (followOnY)
        {
            if (constrainedOnY)
            {
                normalizedPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp(normalizedPosition.y, minY, maxY);
            }
        }
        else
            normalizedPosition.y = originalPosition.y;
        normalizedPosition.z = originalPosition.z;
        transform.position = normalizedPosition;

    }
}
```

I can use this code by attaching it to the camera to follow a target, but the movement is very bad, especially when trying to make a target jump. I think this is a problem because the camera goes a little slower after the target. Help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario I would suggest not having the camera as a child and just write a script to allow it to track. You can easily allow/disallow the y-movement this way and gives you a lot more freedom for camera movement down the road, should you need it.

```
public GameObject player; //assign player gameobject to variable in the inspector
public bool lockY = true;
private Vector3 offset;
private Vector3 tempVect;

void Start()
{
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position; //store initial camera offset.
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    tempVect = player.transform.position + offset;
    if (lockY) // toggle this to allow or disallow y-axis tracking
        tempVect.y -= player.transform.position.y; // remove y component of player position
    transform.position = tempVect;
}
```